# Include Ruby method from external ruby file at run time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I'm creating an internal tools used by informatician colleages (not a public website). I need to export my data in various way and I want to let my colleagues write export methods for their needs.

**So I want to run a specific method of a specific ruby file as a go_to() method, then return.**

The function is located in the rails app (app/views/export/templates/my_template/export.rb)
and I want to run it from my Export Controller, which is fetching the data in a multi step wizard.

**How to "jump" to a specific method** to manipulate data (as a preprocess function) from my Export controller ?

Do I need to Extend my controller ?

```
class ExportController < ApplicationController
require 'spreadsheet'

    # Step 5 : Exporting
    def step5
        # Creating Spreadsheet variable called "book"
        book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
        sheet = book.create_worksheet

        # Selecting points to export
        @project = Project.find(session[:current_project_id])
        @points = @project.points


        # HERE : Jump to app/views/export/templates/my_template/export.rb           
        # WITH SOME PARAMETERS AS @points, book THAT WILL MAKE SOME EXTRA QUERIES
        # THEN COME BACK TO RENDER THE EXCEL FILE WITH THE PROCESSED DATA


        # Sending to browser without saving it on the server
        data = StringIO.new 
        book.write data 
        send_data(data.string, {
            :disposition => 'attachment',
            :encoding => 'utf8',
            :stream => false,
            :type => 'application/excel',
            :filename => 'some_filename.xls'})
        #send_data data.string, :filename => "yourfile.xls", :type =>  "application/vnd.ms-excel", :x_sendfile=>true

        # redirect_to "export#step6" # this is for now not working because of the render of the xls file
    end

end
```

Comment: "Jumping" to a method is just calling it, isn't it? If the method is defined in some file you have to require this file, and if the method is in a module - include this module in the controller. That's pretty strange your method is defined somewhere in the `views` directory. If you need it used in views you can place it in the helper (and require and include this helper into controller).

Comment: Actually nevermind. I think what you said is right. Requiring the file should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have an `.rb` file in your views directory? Looks like it should go in your `models`, or `lib`. Regardless, if it's a class file then `require` it or put it in the right place, then call `data = Export.some_process_method(@points, etc, etc)`.

Comment: I will try to create a librairies of export functions then. Do you know how to do this ? I will place it in the lib directory in place than in the views directory. Extra question : Is it possible to modify multiple variables by passing their "address" to the export function ?

Comment: If you have a bunch of functions that are all related to export, then create an Export class, put all the "functions" in there as class methods, and then call as above. You can return multiple values from a method, and make multiple assignments as follows: `a, b = Export.some_process(@bla, bla, bla)`. If the method returns two values then they will be assigned to `a` and `b` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you trying to explain. Do you what to give you colleagues capability upload ruby file which later should be invoke from specific place of specific controller or what?

p.s. I know is not an answer but I really wanna help and i don't have enough reputation to leave a comment(i am just started)